# SSRS tweak to time expression

Tags: reporting-services

I am currently using this expression to show the previous working day in an SSRS report:

```
=DateAdd("d" 
     , Switch(DatePart("w", Today) = 2, -3
         ,DatePart("w", Today) = 1, -2
         ,True, -1)
     , Today)
```

which works fine.

However I would like the output to be,if I ran the query today for example,:

24/04/2020 23:59:59

Instead of the current 24/04/2020

Please can you advise on how I could add hours, minutes and seconds- 23:59:59 - to the above expression?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a more elegant way of doing this but I based this on you current expression. I've text it and it seems to work OK.

```
=DateAdd("s" 
     , Switch(
          DatePart("w", Today) = 2, (-3 * 86400) -1,
          DatePart("w", Today) = 1, (-2 * 86400) -1,
          True, -85401
            ) 
     , Today)
```

This simply does a datediff in seconds rather than days and then adjusts the amount of seconds to remove by 1

Comment: many thanks for taking the time and trouble to reply - that has worked.